# Twitter API for User Profile and URLclicks

Tags: twitter, google-apps-script

Could you please help me to find the Twitter API, which provides the count of "user profile clicks" and "url clicks"

Thanks,

Aneesh

Answer (score 0):

These values are not available through the Twitter REST API.

Comment: Is there any way to get these numbers?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to get them;  They don't seem to be available through the API.